# Element style according to other class with LESS

Tags: css, class, less

i have this part of less and html markup:

```
<div class="block">
   <div class="post-image"></div>
   <p></p>
</div>
```

and

```
  .post-image {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 35%; height: 80px;

    &.photo {
      width: 100%; height: 180px;
    }
  }

  p {
    width: 64%;
    display: inline-block;

    when (isstring .post-image.photo) {
      width: 100%;
  }
```

I know that this is wrong setup but i just wanna know, Is there any possible to append this paragraph (`p`) style by photo width or class in less?
Much thx for help.

Comment: Do you mean you want a caption underneath the image?

Comment: I have two situation, when img have 100% width and 35%, so when it have this second value i want to drench around it by paragraph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not even technically a LESS thing, but purely a CSS construct for your situation (which, of course, LESS can help you build). Here is what you need as LESS and the resulting CSS for your snippet of HTML (the `.post-image` code is as you already have):

**LESS**

```
p {
  width: 64%;
  display: inline-block;

  .post-image.photo + & {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

**CSS**

```
p {
  width: 64%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.post-image.photo + p {
  width: 100%;
}
```

The second will override the first when the `.photo` class is added to the `.post-image`.